# call textbox[i] from textbox array created by hand before

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My problem is:
There is a button on web-form. It creates 5 textBoxes.
Then, there is another button on the same web-form. It gets values from created textBoxes and make something:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

TextBox[] textbox;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox = new TextBox[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        textbox[i] = new TextBox();
        textbox[i].ID = "textbox[" + i + "]";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox[i]);
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        str += textbox[i].Text;
    }
    Label1.Text = str;
}
```

The error is in Button2_Click at textbox[i] is null. I understand why it is happened, but I don't understand how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Dynamically added controls are lost after postback. Normally you   will keep those control's information in Session  or viewstate and rebuild those controls after postback. Page_Load is a good place to rebuild them.

You will find many articles on how to persist the controls as well as their data, just search with `"asp.net dynamically added controls are lost at postback"`.

Here's an example you can look at:[How to retain values of dynamically created controls in asp.net](http://ruchirac.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-retain-values-of-dynamically.html). Here's another exmple: [Re: Dynamic Controls in Placeholder lossed after postback](http://forums.asp.net/post/1667338.aspx).

Hope it helps!